# No key defined for key on multiple columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am using C# and Entity Framework. I want to define a key for the `SimulationParameter` object as a combination of three columns (Name, StudyId, SimulationId). I don't need an ID column, since the combination of those three elements will always be unique.

***Simulation Parameter:***

```
public class SimulationParameter : IAggregateRoot
    {
        public SimulationParameter()
        {
        }

        public String SimulationId { get; set; }

        public Guid StudyId { get; set; }

        public Study Study { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }        
    }
```

***Simulation Parameter Mapping:***

```
class SimulationParameterMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SimulationParameter>
    {
        public SimulationParameterMap()
        {
          HasKey(e => new {SimulationId = e.SimulationId, Name = e.Name, StudyId = e.StudyId});            

        Property(e => e.SimulationId)
            .IsRequired(); 

        Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired(); 

        Property(e => e.Value)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(e => e.Study)
            .WithMany(e => e.SimulationsParameters)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.StudyId);

        ToTable("SimulationParameters");
        }
    }
```

Now, when I try to create the model, I have the following error:

```
    EntityType 'SimulationParameter' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SimulationParameters: EntityType: EntitySet 'SimulationParameters' is based on type 'SimulationParameter' that has no keys defined.
```

I am really clueless on why this is not valid...

**Edit 1:**

Based on a suggestion, I added the `[Key]` attribute above the field in the model:

```
 public class SimulationParameter : IAggregateRoot
    {
        public SimulationParameter()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        public String SimulationId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public Guid StudyId { get; set; }

        public Study Study { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }

    }
```

And got a different error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'SimulationParameter'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys.
```

**Edit2**

I was able to make it work doing the following:

```
  public class SimulationParameter : IAggregateRoot
    {
        public SimulationParameter()
        {
        }

        [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public String SimulationId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public Guid StudyId { get; set; }

        public Study Study { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public String Value { get; set; }



    }
```

It is still strange though that it isn't working using fluent, I'll keep looking and keep you posted.

Comment: `SimulationParameter` is an object of what class? Can you post the code for your class

Comment: I updated the question with the code.

Comment: What happens if you add `[Key]` above each of those fields in the model? Are you sure its recognizing your fluent code? That should be working

Comment: It is recognizing my fluent code since if I don't put multiple keys, my db gets created. I'll try that.

Comment: I got a different error by putting [Key] above SimulationId, StudyId and Name. `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'SimulationParameter'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys.`

Comment: It should be `[Key, Column(0)]`, `[Key, Column(1)]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a property in another class as primary key: `e.Study.Id`. `SimulationParameter` should also have a `StudyId` (or something like it) in the database. Just take this field into the class and make it part of the key:

```
public class SimulationParameter : IAggregateRoot
{
    public SimulationParameter()
    {
    }

    public String SimulationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Study")]
    public int StudyId { get; set; }
    public Study Study { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }            
}
```

Or, with fluent mapping:

```
HasRequired(e => e.Study)
.WithMany(e => e.SimulationsParameters)
.HasForeignKey(s => s.StudyId);
```

Comment: I am using fluent also, (updated the code), is there something else I need to change in the mapping ? because If I do what you propose and change e.Study.Id to e.StudyId, I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes I do. Do I have, in the mapping, to also add something telling it about StudyId ?

Comment: Do I still do the ForeignKey thing if I use fluent ?

Comment: No, not the attribute.

Comment: Still the same error... I updated the code with your modifications in case you see something else, thanks for your time.